# How to set a custom header using Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: pipe, yql, yahoo-pipes

I'm doing a pipe to retrieve RSS content from a private blogger's blog.
The pipe first send a POST request to https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin to get the Auth token. I use YQL for this (`select * from htmlpost where url="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin" and postdata="Email=...`).
The question is, how could I set a custom header named "Authenticate" with the Auth token inside when retrieving the content of a web?
I'm not experienced in YQL neither in yahoo pipes. I believe that what I'm trying is not possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a yql-table like [this one](https://sites.google.com/site/myopentables/html.get.xml?attredirects=0&d=1) made by myself and use it with a yql query like:

```
use "https://sites.google.com/site/myopentables/html.get.xml?attredirects=0&d=1" as html.get;
select * from html.get where url="someurl" and authorization="auth string";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would still have to write your own YQL datatable but instead of Pedro's answer I would suggest that you use YQL's built in **paramType="header"**.

```
<key id="Authorization" as="authorization" type="xs:string" paramType="header" required="false" />
```

From the [YQL documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-reference.html#yql-opentables-key) about the attributes to :

- header: Add the id and its value as a id: value as an HTTP header to the URL request.